# Lua Serial Communication

Tags: lua, serial-port, arduino

In Lock On: Modern Air Combat game there is export.lua script that allows you to export data from game. I have mannaged to export data to .txt file so far.

My question is

Is it possible and how to send data over serial to my Arduino device?

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you can communicate between Arduino IDE on PC and the board, the communication can be done using Lua on PC end and the Arduino for sure. You can use the '[librs232](https://github.com/ynezz/librs232)' Lua library for serial-port communication (works on Windows and Linux platforms), to open the serial port toward Arduino, set comm parameters (baud-rate, parity, flow-control etc.) and send-receive information with Arduino. The only documentation for the library is an example lua application, but it is well-commented and pretty self-explanatory.

PS> I have no idea about the "Lock On: Modern Air Combat game", and you haven't mentioned what you intend to do with the exported data in text file, and the Arduino. I assume that you've figured that out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another serial-communication lib: https://github.com/edartuz/ul_serial
Works on Windows/Linux, OOP-oriented with concise initialization parameters.